# Can not display user information?

Tags: views, 8, users

I want to display on the user account page the following information :

- the status of the account.
- the roles attached to the accounts.
- registered since the ...
- last connection on ...

The view displays all the information for the administrator account, but with an authenticated user I only have the following information :

- the roles attached to the accounts.
- registered since the ...

How to display all the information for the authenticated user ?

[image]

```
uuid: 88c79c78-6091-4edc-bcd7-464f3a5a3baf
langcode: fr
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - user
id: utilisateur_informations
label: 'Utilisateur informations'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: users_field_data
base_field: uid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Trier par'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: none
        options:
          items_per_page: null
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: views-teaser
          default_row_class: true
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        status:
          id: status
          table: users_field_data
          field: status
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Compte '
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: boolean
          settings:
            format: enabled-disabled
            format_custom_true: ''
            format_custom_false: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: status
          plugin_id: field
        roles_target_id:
          id: roles_target_id
          table: user__roles
          field: roles_target_id
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Rôles '
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          type: separator
          separator: ', '
          entity_type: user
          plugin_id: user_roles
        created:
          id: created
          table: users_field_data
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Membre depuis '
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp_ago
          settings:
            granularity: 2
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: field
        login:
          id: login
          table: users_field_data
          field: login
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Dernière connexion le '
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: short
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: login
          plugin_id: field
      filters: {  }
      sorts: {  }
      title: 'Utilisateur informations'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: raw
          default_argument_options:
            index: 1
            use_alias: false
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            items_per_page: 25
            override: false
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
        uid_1:
          id: uid_1
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: current_user
          default_argument_options: {  }
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            items_per_page: 25
            override: false
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - user
      tags: {  }
  block_1:
    display_plugin: block
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders:
        metatag_display_extender: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - user
      tags: {  }
```

Comment: Have you actually created some authenticated user accounts and logged in with them?

Comment: @Kevin howbrook Yes and that's the problem.

Comment: hi, Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your first contextual argument. You only need this one:
[image]

Comment: This does not change anything, even if I completely remove the contextual filter the problem is still there. In permissions, if I grant "Administer users" it works. I can not grant this permissions to users. How to do ?

Comment: Do you have other answers ?

Comment: does data show in the preview of the views UI ?

Comment: yes, because I am the administrator. If I connect with an authenticated user, I miss my question data. If I grant permission "Administer users", it works. But I do not want to grant this permission.

Answer (score 0):

I imported your view and tried to do it via views module. But I believe you will need to do some custom coding for this. You need to set access permissions per field in Drupal 8.

To learn more about field permissions refer `field_permissions` example module in [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.